# specify python instance to use with sudo apt-get

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I was trying to get alien, so I did this by command line

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
```

at the end of it, it had this prompt

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-setuptools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The first thing I did as a reaction was to check the system version of python

```
(me):~$ python --version
Python 2.5.2
```

I have a virtual environment running 2.7.5 which is more likely to work, but is it possible to specify to use this version of python while running the `sudo apt-get`?

Comment: Even if you find a workaround in the answers; you _really_ need to upgrade your Python version.

Comment: I have an env with python 3.4, but it's not allowed for this project

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `env` while launching apt-get to change your PATH variable to find the virtual environment's version of python first:

```
sudo env PATH=/path/to/virtual/python/binary:$PATH apt-get
```